# How to update a table whose primary key is the primary key in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, cascade

I have these two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE COPIE(IDC VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
                   ETAT CHAR(1)
                     CHECK (ETAT IN ('M','P','D')),
                   IDO VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES OUVRAGE(IDO));

CREATE TABLE PRET(IDC VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES COPIE(IDC),
                  IDE REFERENCES ETUDIANT(IDE),
                  DATEP DATE,
                  DATER DATE,
                  AVIS VARCHAR2(7)
                    CHECK (AVIS IN ('LIKE','DISLIKE')),
                  IDB VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES BIBLIO(IDB),
                  PRIMARY KEY(IDC,IDE,DATEP));
```

so basically im trying to make a procedure which updates ETAT in TABLE COPIE WHERE its datep is not null and dater is null ( in table pret )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, you can use `merge` as following:

```
Merge into copie c
Using (select * from pret
       Where dater is null and datep is not null) t
On (c.idc = t.idc)
When matched then 
Update set c.etat = <value whichever you want>
```

Or you can directly use `update` statement as

```
Update copie c 
Set c.etat = <value whichever you want>
Where c.idc in 
   (select t.idc
      From pret t
     Where dater is null 
       and datep is not null)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that IDC is the primary key or part of the primary key in two tables really shouldn't be an issue. If you want to update `COPIE.ETAT` you should be able to say

```
UPDATE COPIE
  SET ETAT = 'M'
  WHERE IDC = 'whatever'
```

This won't affect anything in table `PRET` because you're not changing the `IDC` field, and the `ETAT` field is not referenced by `PRET`.

Comment: so i can join the two tables with IDC in boht and still able to update ETAT ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow the use of joins in an UPDATE statement, and your question certainly does not appear to address that. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button (just below the question tags) and describe what you're actually trying to do. Thanks.